# RepositoryException: Unable to auto-create value

Tags: jackrabbit

I'm new to Jackrabbit Oak, I'm trying to create nodes for storing files (pdf, word, excel, etc). When I try to create the node by specifying a type similar to this exceptions they are thrown.

> javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Unable to auto-create value for / e0a02fd0-d328-48f7-8874-685c591afe9a / jcr: createdBy.

Example code:

[image: Screenshot]